# not updating value from text field error when alerting a variable in Javascript Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, alert

I'm currently working on a userCP for my URL shortener website and partly on the USERCP you are able to manage your URL's via Jquery. The problem that I'm having is that when alerting the values of a row, it prints the correct URL/Short URL. Which is good.

My problem is when the edit button is pressed, the 2 fields turn into text fields to make them editable, which is also fine, but when I edit them, and click save it alerts the previous URL/short URL. I want it to alert the new value but it doesn't seem to work.

So here's what I've done:

```
<?php while($list = $listURLs->fetch_array()) { ?> *As you can see, i'm looping.*

    <td id="longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>"><a rel="tooltip" title="<?= $list['longURL']; ?>" target="_blank" href="<?= $list['longURL']; ?>"><?= substr($list['longURL'],0,25); ?></a></td>
            <td id="shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>"><input type='text' class='span2' onmouseover="(this.select())" value='http://smurl.es/<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>'/></td>
            <td><?= $list['type']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $time; ?></td>
            <td><?= $list['hits']; ?></td>
            <td><button id="edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>" class='btn btn-warning btn-small' rel='tooltip' title='Edit'><i class="icon icon-edit"></i></button>&nbsp;<button id="del<?= $list['ID']; ?>" class='btn btn-danger btn-small' rel='tooltip' title='Delete'><i class="icon icon-trash"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").click(function() {


                $('#longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<input type='text' id='lurl<?= $list['ID']; ?>' value='<?= $list['longURL']; ?>' />");
                $('#shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<div class='input-prepend'><span class='add-on'>http://smurl.es/</span><input id='surl<?= $list['ID']; ?>' type='text' value='<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>' class='span1' /></div>");
                $("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").attr({"class": "btn btn-info btn-small", "data-original-title": "Click to Save", "id": "save<?= $list['ID']; ?>"});

                });

                var click<?= $list['ID']; ?> = 0;
                $(document).on('click', 'button#save<?= $list['ID']; ?>', function() {
                click<?= $list['ID']; ?> += 1;

                if(click<?= $list['ID']; ?> >= 2) {

                  var shortURL = $('#surl<?= $list['ID']; ?>').val();
                  var longURL = $('#lurl<?= $list['ID']; ?>').val();

                  var name = $("#name").val();
                  var name = $("#name").text();

                  alert("short: " + shortURL + "\n\nLong: " + longURL);

                   $("button#save<?= $list['ID']; ?>").attr({"class": "btn btn-warning btn-small", "data-original-title": "Edit", "id": "edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>"});
                           $('#longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<a target='_blank' href='<?= $list['longURL']; ?>'>" + "<?= $list['longURL']; ?>".substring(0, 25) + "</a>");
                   $('#shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<input type='text' class='span2' onmouseover='(this.select())' value='http://smurl.es/<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>'/>");
                 click<?= $list['ID']; ?> = 0;



                }
                });
            </script>
        <?php 
            }
        }
         ?>
```

As you can see, I use:

```
$('#longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<input type='text' id='lurl<?= $list['ID']; ?>' value='<?= $list['longURL']; ?>' />");
$('#shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<div class='input-prepend'><span class='add-on'>http://smurl.es/</span><input id='surl<?= $list['ID']; ?>' type='text' value='<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>' class='span1' /></div>");
```

to update the text into text field to make it editable. But it doesn't work...

It just alerts the same previous URL before I try to edit it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the javascript is evaluated before the values are changed,

i.e.,

```
var shortURL = $('#surl<?= $list['ID']; ?>').val();
var longURL = $('#lurl<?= $list['ID']; ?>').val();
```

the fragment above is evaluated at first, when the click event is triggered, the evaluated result is executed (instead of evaluate it within click event then execute it)

you can confirm this by right-click on the web page in your browser and view page source (the rendered html code) to see the real javascript in your page.

Comment: Hi, I have checked my source, and yes the code is there so I'm sure it's being loaded when everything else is too.

Comment: Just to be clear, what I mean is right-click on the web page and see the rendered html code.